# enable Xcode Developer Mode on AD bound user (Mavericks)

Tags: macos, xcode

How can I enable Xcode Developer Mode on AD bound user, I tried

```
/usr/sbin/dseditgroup -o edit -t group -a "AD/Domain Users" _developer
```

I get the error message "Record was not found"

Could anybody help?

Comment: If you want to merge your accounts and regain contol of your question, including being able to comment on answers then please go to http://superuser.com/contact

Answer (score 0):

`_developer` is commonly a **LOCAL** OSX group. `dseditgroup` has the ability to modify AD groups if the userID running the command has the rights to.

If you're trying to add domain ID to a local OSX group, you should be using `dscl` instead. Here's an example of adding a domain group to a local OSX group

```
dscl . -append /Groups/_developer GroupMembership some_user
```

The command above points to the local node (the `.` reference) and adds *some_user* to the `GroupMembership` property of the _developer group (referenced as `/Groups/_developer`). Note that you may need to run this command as root depending on the group you wish to modify.